# Check to see that every field in an array equals a value

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array

I've got data like this:

```
 this.registrations =   [{
    event: "Juniors 18s",
    day: "Friday",
    group: "nonpro",
    players: [{
      first: "Mary",
      last: "Mack",
      email: "marymack@dressedinblack.com",
      phone: "8888675309",
      signed: false,
      waivers: [{
        has_signed: true,
        token: "ab",
        url: "somesite.com",
        signatureUrl: "someothersite.com",
        message: "Minor waiver"
        },
        {
        has_signed: true,
        token: "ab",
        url: "somesite.com",
        signatureUrl: "someothersite.com",
        message: "Parental waiver"
        }
      ]
    },
    {... another record like that one}
    ]
```

Is there a way to display if each player has signed all the waivers?  I know there is a .every function but I'm not sure how to use it with this nested data structure.

I was thinking something like below, but it didn't work:

```
this.registrations.has_signed = this.registrations.waivers.every( waiver => waiver.has_signed === true )
```

Then I tried this one, which at least seems like it might be closer to a win (but not quite).  the players.signed property isn't used, but someone put it in there as false by default, so I'd love to use it:

```
  this.registrations.forEach(reg => {
    reg.players.forEach(p => {
      if (p.waivers.every(waiver => waiver.has_signed === true)) {
        p.signed = true;
      } else {
        p.signed = false;
      }
      return reg;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do the required task.

```
const modifiedPlayers = this.registrations.map(reg => reg.players).map(player => {
  player.signed = player.waivers.every(waiver => waiver.has_signed);
  return player;
});

this.registrations.players = modifiedPlayers;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.registrations.has_signed = false;
this.registrations.forEach(registration => 
    registration.players.forEach(player => 
        this.registrations.has_signed = player.waivers.every(waiver => waiver.has_signed)
    )
);
```

You have to loop the outer arrays first to get to the waivers and use `every` to find out the `has-signed`.